# LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'libclamav.lib'

Tags: c++, c

I am using Microsoft Visual Studio 2010, and i am working on open source Clamav, my code is given below which is generating an error

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>  
#include <string.h>
#include <io.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <clamav.h>


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
int fd, ret;
unsigned long int size = 0;
unsigned int sigs = 0;
long double mb;
const char *virname;
struct cl_engine *engine;


if(argc != 2) {
printf("Usage: %s file\n", argv[0]);
return 2;
}

if((fd = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY)) == -1) {
printf("Can't open file %s\n", argv[1]);
return 2;
}

if((ret = cl_init(CL_INIT_DEFAULT)) != CL_SUCCESS) {
printf("Can't initialize libclamav: %s\n", cl_strerror(ret));
return 2;
}

if(!(engine = cl_engine_new())) {
printf("Can't create new engine\n");
return 2;
}

/* load all available databases from default directory */
if((ret = cl_load(cl_retdbdir(), engine, &sigs, CL_DB_STDOPT)) != CL_SUCCESS) {
printf("cl_load: %s\n", cl_strerror(ret));
close(fd);
    cl_engine_free(engine);
return 2;
}

printf("Loaded %u signatures.\n", sigs);

/* build engine */
if((ret = cl_engine_compile(engine)) != CL_SUCCESS) {
printf("Database initialization error: %s\n", cl_strerror(ret));;
    cl_engine_free(engine);
close(fd);
return 2;
}

/* scan file descriptor */
if((ret = cl_scandesc(fd, &virname, &size, engine, CL_SCAN_STDOPT)) == CL_VIRUS) {
printf("Virus detected: %s\n", virname);
} else {
if(ret == CL_CLEAN) {
    printf("No virus detected.\n");
} else {
    printf("Error: %s\n", cl_strerror(ret));
    cl_engine_free(engine);
    close(fd);
    return 2;
}
}
close(fd);

/* free memory */
cl_engine_free(engine);

/* calculate size of scanned data */
mb = size * (CL_COUNT_PRECISION / 1024) / 1024.0;
printf("Data scanned: %2.2Lf MB\n", mb);

return ret == CL_VIRUS ? 1 : 0;
}
```

the following error is generated
LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'libclamav.lib'

kindly guide me

Comment: Conventionally what's libXYZ.a in UNIX-world is XYZ.lib in Windows-world.  You appear to be mixing the two worlds.

Comment: There is probably nothing wrong with your code. The error is in the way you compile it. Please give some detail.

Comment: Added library directories to project properties (Configuration Properties->Linker->General->Additional Library Directories)?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You get an LNK1181 error in Visual Studio when the .lib or .obj files that are specified during linking are not found in the current directory, any of the directories that are specified by the `LIBPATH` linker option, or any of the directories that are specified in the `LIB` environment variable.

You may add the directory that contains `libclamav.lib` library file to the `LIBPATH` to resolve the problem (this instructions may vary a bit depending on your Visual Studio version):

1. In Solution Explorer, right-click the project, and then click **Properties**.
2. In the **Property Pages** dialog box, expand **Linker**, and then click **General**.
3. In the **Additional Library Directories** field, specify the path where `libclamav.lib` resides.

The error can also happen when the `LIBPATH` contains spaces. If that's the case, move the library to a path without spaces or put quotation marks around the path.

Comment: I wish I could give you 1000 upvotes! I am trying to update a legacy project, and the LIBPATH had spaces in it. I've been searching for what seems like hours, and no one else suggested that. I have no idea how it was working on the original dev environment! Maybe they also happened to have it in the LIB envirable... In any event, I don't know how moderner versions of VS deal with that, but VC++ 6 (Don't ask!) did not fail gracefully whatsoever.

Comment: Just in case anyone else stumbles upon this, my mistake was more basic and silly. I was attempting to build within the "project only". Make sure to build your dependencies first! So right click on your project file and click build.

Answer (score 1):

You can also fix it by specifying the library path in DOS "8.3" format.

To get the 8.3 form, do (at the command line):

```
DIR /AD /X
```

recursively through every level of the directories.