# LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'lib.obj'

Tags: visual-c++

I am compiling a server on Microsoft Visual Studio 2015, generating the solution using CMake. The project is correctly set up to generate a 64-bit release, and the following variables work:

> MYSQL_EXECUTABLE = C:/MariaDB/bin
>
> MYSQL_INCLUDEDIR = C:/MariaDB/include/mysql
>
> MYSQL_LIBRARY = C:/MariaDB/lib

Everything builds correctly except at the end when I get the following:

> 17>LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'C:\MariaDB\lib.obj'

As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18352101/link-fatal-error-lnk1181-cannot-open-input-file-libclamav-lib), I have appended "C:\MariaDB\lib" to "Additional Library Directories". However, because it's looking for "lib.obj" rather than anything with a reasonable name, I've no idea how to fix it. Any ideas?

Comment: Just google "MYSQL_LIBRARY define" to see examples.  Note how it should not be a directory but the actual MySQL client library that needs to be linked.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into that.