# pip install av produces a LINK 1181 error

Tags: python, c++, visual-studio, ffmpeg, pip

initially, pip install av asked me to download visual C++ 14 build tools which I did
but it is still showing me LINK 1181 errors

I need this pyAV pakcage which is obtained by pip install av for a project, but it always shows some kind of error linked with C++ and i also have ffmpeg installed.

```
C:\Users\manop>pip install av
Collecting av
  Using cached av-7.0.0.tar.gz (2.3 MB)
Building wheels for collected packages: av
  Building wheel for av (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'c:\users\manop\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\manop\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-rydo0uqj\\av\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\manop\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-rydo0uqj\\av\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\manop\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-oti9y28m'
       cwd: C:\Users\manop\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-rydo0uqj\av\
  Complete output (38 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\av
  copying av\datasets.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\av
  copying av\deprecation.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\av
  copying av\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\av
  copying av\__main__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\av
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\av\audio
  copying av\audio\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\av\audio
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\av\codec
  copying av\codec\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\av\codec
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\av\container
  copying av\container\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\av\container
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\av\data
  copying av\data\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\av\data
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\av\filter
  copying av\filter\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\av\filter
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\av\sidedata
  copying av\sidedata\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\av\sidedata
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\av\subtitles
  copying av\subtitles\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\av\subtitles
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\av\video
  copying av\video\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\av\video
  running build_ext
  running config
  writing build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\include\pyav\config.h
  running cythonize
  building 'av.buffer' extension
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\src
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\src\av
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\bin\HostX64\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Ic:\users\manop\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\include -Ibuild\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\include -Iinclude -Ic:\users\manop\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\include -Ic:\users\manop\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\include -Ibuild\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\Include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt" /Tcsrc\av\buffer.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\src\av\buffer.obj
  buffer.c
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\bin\HostX64\x64\link.exe /nologo /INCREMENTAL:NO /LTCG /DLL /MANIFEST:EMBED,ID=2 /MANIFESTUAC:NO /LIBPATH:c:\users\manop\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\PCbuild\amd64 /LIBPATH:c:\users\manop\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\libs /LIBPATH:c:\users\manop\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\libs /LIBPATH:c:\users\manop\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\PCbuild\amd64 "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\Lib\x64" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.18362.0\um\x64" /LIBPATH:C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319 "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\x64" swresample.lib swscale.lib avdevice.lib avutil.lib avcodec.lib avformat.lib avfilter.lib /EXPORT:PyInit_buffer build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\src\av\buffer.obj /OUT:build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\av\buffer.cp37-win_amd64.pyd /IMPLIB:build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\src\av\buffer.cp37-win_amd64.lib /OPT:NOREF
  LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'swresample.lib'
  error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.16.27023\\bin\\HostX64\\x64\\link.exe' failed with exit status 1181
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for av
  Running setup.py clean for av
Failed to build av
Installing collected packages: av
    Running setup.py install for av ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\manop\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\manop\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-rydo0uqj\\av\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\manop\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-rydo0uqj\\av\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\manop\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-xac0xiy4\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\manop\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\Include\av'
         cwd: C:\Users\manop\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-rydo0uqj\av\
    Complete output (38 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\av
    copying av\datasets.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\av
    copying av\deprecation.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\av
    copying av\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\av
    copying av\__main__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\av
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\av\audio
    copying av\audio\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\av\audio
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\av\codec
    copying av\codec\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\av\codec
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\av\container
    copying av\container\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\av\container
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\av\data
    copying av\data\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\av\data
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\av\filter
    copying av\filter\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\av\filter
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\av\sidedata
    copying av\sidedata\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\av\sidedata
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\av\subtitles
    copying av\subtitles\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\av\subtitles
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\av\video
    copying av\video\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\av\video
    running build_ext
    running config
    writing build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\include\pyav\config.h
    running cythonize
    building 'av.buffer' extension
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\src
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\src\av
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\bin\HostX64\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Ibuild\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\include -Iinclude -Ic:\users\manop\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\include -Ic:\users\manop\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\include -Ic:\users\manop\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\include -Ibuild\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\Include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt" /Tcsrc\av\buffer.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\src\av\buffer.obj
    buffer.c
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\bin\HostX64\x64\link.exe /nologo /INCREMENTAL:NO /LTCG /DLL /MANIFEST:EMBED,ID=2 /MANIFESTUAC:NO /LIBPATH:c:\users\manop\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\PCbuild\amd64 /LIBPATH:c:\users\manop\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\libs /LIBPATH:c:\users\manop\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\libs /LIBPATH:c:\users\manop\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\PCbuild\amd64 "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\Lib\x64" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.18362.0\um\x64" /LIBPATH:C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319 "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\x64" avutil.lib avfilter.lib swresample.lib swscale.lib avformat.lib avcodec.lib avdevice.lib /EXPORT:PyInit_buffer build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\src\av\buffer.obj /OUT:build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\av\buffer.cp37-win_amd64.pyd /IMPLIB:build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\src\av\buffer.cp37-win_amd64.lib /OPT:NOREF
    LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'avutil.lib'
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.16.27023\\bin\\HostX64\\x64\\link.exe' failed with exit status 1181
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\manop\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\manop\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-rydo0uqj\\av\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\manop\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-rydo0uqj\\av\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\manop\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-xac0xiy4\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\manop\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\Include\av' Check the logs for full command output.
```

These are my visual C++ selections:
[my visual studio installer individual components selection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Ltc6.png)

Comment: did you check [here](http://docs.mikeboers.com/pyav/develop/overview/installation.html#windows) for installation

Comment: @Jeril yes I checked there, but what I do not understand is
`On Windows you must indicate the location of your FFmpeg, e.g.:

python setup.py build --ffmpeg-dir=C:\ffmpeg`

Comment: did this `python setup.py build --ffmpeg-dir=C:\ffmpeg` work

Comment: Oh so to clarify I did download the FFmpeg and extracted in the location C:\FFmpeg

and this is the output of the comand:

`C:\Users\manop>python setup.py build --ffmpeg-dir=C:\FFmpeg
python: can't open file 'setup.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory`

Comment: okay, you need to download the zip file from pyAV github. Then you need to unzip, and go inside the folder. You will find a file named `setup.py`, there you need to run the command `python setup.py build --ffmpeg-dir=C:\ffmpeg`

Comment: @Jeril okay so the good thing is after going into the folder of pyAV that i got from github and running that command I saw some progress but at the very end, this happened:

`LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'avutil.lib'
error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.16.27023\\bin\\HostX64\\x64\\link.exe' failed with exit status 1181
`

Comment: can you try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18352476/2825570), and [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/help/815645/you-receive-a-fatal-error-lnk1181-error-message-when-you-build-a-manag)

Comment: @Jeril so those also did not work but I eventually gave up on pip install av and looked into conda
Just downloaded miniconda and did `conda install av` and everything worked, so the conclusion is the best way to use pyav is through conda.